# Plotting IP addresses on axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I have been trying to plot [parallel coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates) with two axes. One being the IP addresses and other the number of requests sent by an IP address in a single day, using D3.js.

I used the direct implementation from http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/.

When the number of discrete IP addresses increases above 1000, the IP address axis stops showing up.

Just to test, I tried integer values instead of IP addresses, with even more than 10,000 unique values it worked fine.

I also tried string with only one '.' in them instead of 4 which are in IP addresses, and it worked fine.

But for IP addresses it doesn't.

Any specific this I might be looking into ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? This isn't the right kind of graph for this. IP addresses are discrete entities. Their numerical properties don't matter, and therefore it doesn't make sense to plot a graph where the vertical axis corresponds to the components of an IP address. I'm not sure what would be a good way of graphing them though. Maybe sort them in order of number of requests, then draw a bar chart. Or maybe you could do something more interesting if they're divided into blocks.

Comment: [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/wtb4hj5e/1/) with 1000 randomly generated IP addresses mapped onto an ordinal scale (which is crazy, but it renders fine). Is this a similar setup to what you're trying to do, and if so, can you reproduce you problem there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the author or parallel corrdinates library answered himself at the google groups :

> It's creating an ordinal dimension, but then hiding the axis because
>   there are more than 60.
>
> https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates/blob/master/d3.parcoords.js#L173

Still wondering, why an upper limit though ?